# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument it reads self as a parameter

Tags: python, oop, positional-argument

I'm new at programming and I'm learning Python. The code should be very simple. The goal should be implement a calculator that does additions between numbers.
It returns this error:

**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number_2'

So it's like it reads self as a parameter, but I can't figure out why.
I'm using Linux Ubuntu 19 as operative system. 
Here's my code:

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, number_1, number_2):
        self.number_1=number_1
        self.number_2=number_2

    def add(self):
        print(f"{number_1}+{number_2}={number_1+number_2}")

if __name__=="__main__":
    c=Calculator('Casio')
    c.add(2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't reading `self` as a parameter here, but `'Casio'` which it is storing as `number_1`. As the error message reads, it is missing `number 2`. If you want `add()` to be able to take arbitrary values, you will need to add them as arguments to that method rather than to the `__init__()` function.

Comment: That's way better explanation than writin a code without one (Thumbs Up!)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass parameters to the add function and not to `__init__` which instantiates the class.

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name

    def add(self, number_1, number_2):
        print(f"{number_1}+{number_2}={number_1+number_2}")

if __name__=="__main__":
    c=Calculator('Casio')
    c.add(2,3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, guys!

Answer (score 0):

When you are initializing the object `'c'`, you are running the `init` method, and you therefore need to pass in both parameters to the `init` method. So, you are required to give both `'number_1'` and `'number_2'` when you create the object. You passed in only`'Casio'`, which python is interpreting as `'number_1'`. Python is also interpreting that there is no `'number_2'`. Here are some solutions:
1: You could make the add() function have the two arguments that `init` has (`'number_1'` and `'number_2'`) and have the only arguments for `init` be `self` and `'name'`. Then, you could have the `init` method only do `self.name = name` and nothing else. 2: You could make the arguments `'number_1'` and `'number_2'` optional by making a default variable for them if you do not enter it:

```
def __init__(self, number_1="1", number_2="2"):
```